# Installing CocoaPods using Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: xcode5, cocoapods

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 I'm trying to install CocoaPods. I got this from terminal:

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.29.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.29.0
1 gem installed
MARIAMs-MacBook-Pro:~ mariam$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

Then nothing is happen!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file called `Podfile` to your project folder with information on what dependencies to install. For more info, see here under Get Started:

http://cocoapods.org/

Comment: Now sudo gem install cocoa pods works, But when I run pod setup I got /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 22 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) @SevenBits

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem by following these tutorials: http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion  http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2013/02/01/troubleshooting-cocoapods-installation/  @SevenBits

Comment: Then please post what you did as an answer and accept answer so that others can benefit from what you did.